# How can I group nearby numbers in ruby?

Tags: ruby, numbers

```
[1.5, 7, 3, 3.1, 3.3, 2.5, 6, 6.5, 5.4, 9, 10, 8]
```

How can I group numbers that have a maximum difference of 2?

```
[1.3, 3, 3.1, 3.3, 2.5]

[6, 6.5, 5.4, 7]

[8, 9, 10]
```

Comment: Are these in arrays?

Comment: where did `1.3` come from? Why does the order change sometimes and not other times? isn't 7 within 2 of 8 and 9?

Comment: yes I thiniking in aproximate method but it is not feasible for this purpose

Comment: decimal 1.3   , 3.1

Comment: Please show us what you have tried.

Comment: It appears that you wish to group elements of the array into arrays that each have the property that if `a` and `b` are any pair of its elements, `(a-b).abs <=2`. If so, there are in general multiple groupings that have this property, so the problem is not well-specified.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As is often the case, Ruby has a tool for this:

```
a = [ 1.5,7,3,3.1,3.3,2.5,6,6.5,5.4,9,10,8 ]

a.chunk_while do |prev,val|
  (val - prev).abs <= 2
end

a.to_a
# => [[1.5], [7], [3, 3.1, 3.3, 2.5], [6, 6.5, 5.4], [9, 10, 8]]
```

The [`chunk_while`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-chunk_while) method takes two values, the previous value and the current value. It splits when that block returns a logically false value.

Comment: I think you need to sort the array before processing chunk_while.

Comment: @Mohanraj That's an option, but it's not clear if that was the intent. They may be in some kind of temporal sequence.

Comment: Perhaps appending `.reject(&:one?)` to remove non-chunks.

Comment: Also, `chunk_while` returns an Enumerator. You won't get the array you show unless you call `to_a` on the result: `a.chunk_while { |prev, val| (val - prev).abs <= 2 }.to_a`

Comment: It is unusual to see an answer that proposes a method that returns a value that differs from the one desired by the OP, doubly-so when that answer has been awarded the greenie! Still, I can see how you arrived at an interpretation of the question that made it answerable. :-)